# DROP TRIGGER using variable to define trigger's name

Tags: database, postgresql, variables, triggers

I have two environments, each of them have different trigger's name and I want to use the same script on both envs to drop a trigger I have...

The problem is, when I do as follows:

```
variable := 'trigger_name';

DROP TRIGGER variable ON my_table;
```

it tries to DROP a trigger named 'variable' not 'trigger_name' as I expected...
How can I do such thing?

Thank you in advance!
-B.J.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`. You're already using PL/PgSQL, so just:

```
variable := 'trigger_name';

EXECUTE format('DROP TRIGGER %I ON my_table', variable);
```